# XSLT count all sibling elements before empty node

Tags: xml, xslt

This is a skeleton of the type of XML files I am working on.

```
<table><tr>
<td>x</td>
<td>y</td>
<td>q</td>
<td>z</td>
<td></td>
<td>o</td>
</tr></table>
```

I want to count all sibling elements before first empty  node.
In example I want 4 to be returned from the element above.

I tried `<xsl:variable name="NumFields" select="count(preceding-sibling::table/tr[1]/td[.=''])" />`  but it returns 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are positioned on the document node (or rather, the parent of the `table` node), the expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(table/tr[1]/td[.=''][1]/preceding-sibling::*)" />
```

If you are positioned on the `table` node though, just shorten it to this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(tr[1]/td[.=''][1]/preceding-sibling::*)" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly. Really appreciate.

Comment: @marionetek: Rather than thank in a comment, please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Find you answer code in below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//tr[1]//td[. = ''][1]/preceding::td)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```